# Insert from one table with different structure to another?

Tags: mysql

I want to dump everything from table `Temporal`:

```
Tipo | Tipo2 | Palabra | Tiempo | Persona | Numero | Raiz
```

To table `Verbos`:

```
ID | Tipo | Tipo2 | Palabra | Tiempo | Persona | Numero | Raiz | Usuario | Date
```

Doing:`INSERT INTO Verbos SELECT * FROM Temporal` doesn't work due table structure. How do I do it so it ignores non specified columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Verbos (Tipo, Tipo2, Palabra, Tiempo, Persona, Numero, Raiz)
SELECT Tipo, Tipo2, Palabra, Tiempo, Persona, Numero, Raiz FROM Temporal
```

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly specify the fields into which to insert and the fields that matters from the source table like:

```
INSERT INTO Verbos (Tipo, Tipo2, ....) SELECT Tipo, Tipo2,  .... FROM ...
```